# Create multi-string registry values in NSIS

Tags: registry, nsis

I tried to create package for my application, I can create registry entry for this application, but only for string type:

```
WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "Publisher" "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"
```

How do I create multi-string values?

Comment: The documentation does not appear to list such a function, but you may call `RegOpenKeyEx()`, `RegSetValueEx()` and `RegCloseKey()` manually by using the [System.dll plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixD.html#useful_system_plugin). Alternatively, you may prepare a temporary *.reg* file and invoke *regedit.exe* to import that for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Registry plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Registry_plug-in) has support for a variety of types, including MULTI_SZ.

Alternatively, take a look at this [example script](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/REG_MULTI_SZ_Reader) using the System plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I just added basic support for WriteRegMultiStr to NSIS but you will have to wait for NSIS v3.02 to use it.

In the mean time you can:

- Use the [Registry plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Registry_plug-in) as suggested by idleberg
- Execute Reg.exe with nsExec or [`Regedit.exe /S file.reg`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/82821) with `ExecWait`
- Use the System plug-in (My code or [this from the Wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/REG_MULTI_SZ_Editor))

NSIS v3.0+:

```
!include WinCore.nsh
!include Util.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!macro RegMultiStr_Free list
System::Free ${list}
!macroend
!macro RegMultiStr_Begin list new
StrLen ${list} `${new}`
System::Call '*(&t${list}s,&t1"",&t1"")p.s' `${new}`
Pop ${list}
!macroend
!macro RegMultiStr_Append list new
Push ${list}
Push `${new}`
!insertmacro CallArtificialFunction RegMultiStr_AppendImp
Pop ${list}
!macroend
!macro RegMultiStr_AppendImp
System::Store S
Pop $2 ; New string
Pop $1 ; List
System::Call KERNEL32::GlobalSize(pr1)i.r3 ; $3 = TotSize
StrLen $4 $2
System::Call '*(&i$3,&t$4,&t1)p.r5'
System::Copy $5 $1
IntOp $3 $3 - ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE}
System::Call '*$5(&i$3,&t$4s,&t1"",&t1"")' $2
!insertmacro RegMultiStr_Free $1
Push $5
System::Store L
!macroend
!macro RegMultiStr_Write hk subkey name list
Push ${hk}
Push `${subkey}`
Push `${name}`
Push ${list}
!insertmacro CallArtificialFunction RegMultiStr_WriteImp
!macroend
!macro RegMultiStr_WriteImp
System::Store S
Pop $4 ; List
Pop $3 ; Name
Pop $2 ; SubKey
Pop $1 ; Root HK
System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegCreateKey(ir1, tr2, *p0r5)i.r0' ; $5 = HKEY 
${If} $0 = 0
    StrCpy $7 $4 ; list items pointer
    loop:
        System::Call KERNEL32::lstrlen(t)(pr7)i.r6
        IntOp $0 $0 + ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE} ; \0
        ${IfThen} $6 = 0 ${|} Goto Write ${|}
        !if "${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE}" > 1
        IntOp $6 $6 * ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE}
        !endif
        IntOp $0 $0 + $6
        IntOp $6 $6 + ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE} ; \0
        ${IntPtrOp} $7 $7 + $6
        Goto loop
    write:
        System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegSetValueEx(pr5, tr3, i0, i7, pr4, ir0)i.r0'
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegCloseKey(pr5)'
${EndIf}
System::Store L
!macroend

!include WinCore.nsh
Section
!insertmacro RegMultiStr_Begin $0 "Foo"
!insertmacro RegMultiStr_Append $0 "Bar"
!insertmacro RegMultiStr_Write ${HKEY_CURRENT_USER} "Software\NSIS\Test" "MultiStrTest" $0
!insertmacro RegMultiStr_Append $0 "B a z"
!insertmacro RegMultiStr_Write ${HKEY_CURRENT_USER} "Software\NSIS\Test" "Test 2" $0
!insertmacro RegMultiStr_Free $0
SectionEnd
```